# JSF Primefaces component's id having an expression language is evaluated to empy string

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Having the following xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="COTreeForm">
            <p:tree value="#{COBean.root}" var="node" id="COTree" dynamic="true" selectionMode="single">
                <p:ajax event="select" update="@(.coDetailsPanel)" listener="#{COBean.onNodeSelect}" />

                <p:treeNode id="COtreeNode" type="customerOrder" icon="ui-icon-co">
                    <p:outputPanel  id="CO_#{node.key}"> CO: #{node.key} </p:outputPanel>
                    <!--  <p:draggable for="CO_#{node.key}" helper="clone" />  -->  
                </p:treeNode>

                <p:treeNode id="COItreeNode" type="customerOrderItem">
                    <p:outputPanel id="COI_#{node.key}" styleClass="ui-tree-node-label-coi"> COI: #{node.key} </p:outputPanel>
                    <!--  <p:draggable for="COI_#{node.key}" helper="clone" />  -->
                </p:treeNode>

            </p:tree>

    </h:form>
```

The `<p:outputPanel  id="CO_#{node.key}"> CO: #{node.key} </p:outputPanel>` is evaluated to the following HTML code:

```
<span id="COTreeForm:COTree:0:CO_"> CO: customer1_co1 </span>
```

Why `#{node.key}` is evaluated to an empty string for the id attribute?! Please notice that it's evaluated correctly as the tag content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `id` (and `binding`) attributes are evaluated during view build time. The `#{node}` is however only available during view render time. For a more detailed explanation, read [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Just don't use `_#{node.key}` at all in all your `id` and `for` attributes. JSF/PrimeFaces will already autogenerate the right unique client IDs depending on the currently iterated tree node.

Comment: Then I have to get the outputPanel's content to obtain the Customer Order Id. How can I get the UIComponent in the ManagedBean based on its ID? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on why and when exactly you would like to do that. Is it during `onNodeSelect()`? Just get it from `NodeSelectEvent` argument.